# How to get JSON data from PHP file NOT using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, json

I've got array send from php that I'm sending over JSON to javascript file. It works using jquery.GET, but I want to use just javascript. I know there's a way, but I can't find it and I bet there's a folk that knows the answer.

This is my code for jquery:

```
$.get('loadSomething.php', function(data) {

   var dataSomething = data.something;

       // Then working with the data I received from PHP file

}
```

I want the same thing but using only javascript.

Comment: I know it is, but on mobile platform it's slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying object of ajax functionality is called [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest), but browser support especially older ones varies greatly in support of features or even the way you get a hold of this object, see the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#Browser_compatibility) table of the MDN page. Generally you don't want to reinvent the whole compatibility mess that JQuery and other frameworks do for you.

This [getting started guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started) should prove itself helpful.